# vb.net app converts dates correctly on one machine but not on another - GB/US formats

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, date-conversion

I've written an app which brings in a CSV export from our HR system, loops through all the records and applies the values from the HR system to active directory.

It works a treat, and when running on my machine i get no errors whatsoever.

When running it on one of our servers, where it is ultimately going to live and will be executed by a service account, I get date conversion errors...

```
 System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "21/08/2020" to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

Right at the start of my code I'm defining the region...

```
    Dim ukCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ukCulture
```

And if I query current culture at runtime, it shows 'en-GB', so that seems right.
If i write out the date strings, they all look right, and the compare operation is working fine.

The error seems to occur in this section of code...

```
 Dim converted_hr_accountexpiry_timestamp= hr_row(0).Item("Termination Date") & ""
 Dim hr_termdate_var() As String = converted_hr_accountexpiry_timestamp.split("/")
 updatescript = updatescript.Replace("$x", "'" & hr_termdate_var(0) & "'") _
                    .Replace("$y", "'" & hr_termdate_var(1) & "'") _
                    .Replace("$z", "'" & hr_termdate_var(2) & "'")
```

So for context, this code is building up a powershell script which is executed to make the necessary changes in AD.
The section of that powershell code that we're looking at here is this...

```
 $server = "MyPrimaryDNSServer.FQDN"
 $exp = get-date -Day $x -Month $y -Year $z -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00
 $expirydate = $exp.ToUniversalTime().AddDays(1)
```

It seems clear that its trying to use a US date format, because if the date provided would match an acceptable US date, ie 3/5/2020, then it will accept it and the wrong date will be applied. The error is only thrown when the day (dd) portion of the date would not be accepted as MM on an american format date, ie 31/07/2020.

And to re-iterate; this issue doesnt happen on my machine, only on the server that will eventually execute the application. I've been through all the region settings on that device itself and everything is set to united kingdom, with the correct dd/MM/yyyy formats for dates.
I'm at a total loss on this one and pulling out what little hair i have left.

Any suggestions/help appriciated!

**EDIT 1:**

This is the full exception, minus the users name obvs...

```
 Error with account : Joe Bloggs (1010245)
 System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "24/07/2020" to type 'Date' is not valid.
 at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDate(String Value)
 at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareObject2(Object Left, Object Right, Boolean TextCompare)
 at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareObjectEqual(Object Left, Object Right, Boolean TextCompare)
 at Atlas.Main.GetAccountsWithUpdates()
```

**EDIT 2:**

So it looks like there are two errors occuring, which is why I couldnt find it by commenting each related line out in turn.

This is definately one of the erroring lines...

```
 converted_ad_expiry_timestamp = converted_ad_expiry_timestamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Split(" ")(0)
```

The value returned is a datetime not a date, so i use tostring and split it on the space to grab just the date portion.

The second error seems to occur in here...

```
 If Not (converted_hr_expiry_timestamp = converted_ad_expiry_timestamp) Then updateme = True : If (hr_row(0).Item("Termination Date")) = "" Then account_expiration_date = "$null" Else account_expiration_date = converted_hr_expiry_timestamp
```

Comment: I don't see a conversion or assignment between a `String` and a `Date` in the code you show.  The part where you say "The error seems to occur in this section of code..." looks like it's all string manipulation.  You may need to edit the question to include a few additional lines here.

Comment: good point @Craig - I seem to have left missed the first line there - edited accordingly now

Comment: That first line still looks like it's on the string manipulation side (or date-to-string conversion side), though.  Given the error, I'd be focusing on something that tries to go from one of the strings to a date.  Is the exception happening in the VB or the Powershell or the interface between?

Comment: The error is happening in the VB... I can demonstrate this because if I comment out the powershell bits all together the exception is still thrown. I'll try and comment some of the other bits out now to see if i can narrow it down.

Comment: The stack trace is showing that it's failing on an equality comparison.  The most likely place for that to show up would be in an `If` statement.

Comment: Yes, indeed it would seem you are spot on... although in going through it line by line, there seems to be two errors, one in the if statement on the HR date and one slightly earlier on the AD date.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem revolves around `converted_ad_expiry_timestamp` which seems to be a `Date` (the VB type is an alias for a .NET `DateTime`).  You put it into a specific localized format via `converted_ad_expiry_timestamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` and then rely on automated conversion to turn it back into a `Date`.  The way to avoid the problem you see here (where the automated conversion uses the system locale to decide the format) is to use one of the `Parse` or `ParseExact` family to control the conversion yourself.  With `Parse`, you can specify the locale to use, or with `ParseExact` you can specify the format.

Similarly, when you attempt to compare them in `If Not (converted_hr_expiry_timestamp = converted_ad_expiry_timestamp) Then ...`, the first item in the comparison is a string; if you want to do this comparison, you need to either use `ToString` on the ad_expiry or parse the hr_expiry into a `Date`.

I would also recommend using `Option Strict` if you can to turn these implicit conversions into errors, or if that would introduce to many issues, at least turn on the warning for implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is just working around the problem, and will stop it working locally for you (or rather move the problem to your machine), but if it's only ever going to be run on that server can you not just swap X and Y values?

```
Dim converted_hr_accountexpiry_timestamp= hr_row(0).Item("Termination Date") & ""
Dim hr_termdate_var() As String = converted_hr_accountexpiry_timestamp.split("/")
updatescript = updatescript.Replace("$x", "'" & hr_termdate_var(1) & "'") _
                .Replace("$y", "'" & hr_termdate_var(0) & "'") _
                .Replace("$z", "'" & hr_termdate_var(2) & "'")
```

Alternatively, if you want it to work on both systems then maybe a check before running the offending code is in order, something like this has worked for me in the past:

```
Try
    Dim TempTimeString As String = "31/01/2020 01:00 AM"
    Dim ConvertedTime As Date
    ConvertedTime = DateTime.Parse(TempTimeString)
    '''Don't swap X and Y as it was able to convert
Catch ex As Exception
    '''swap X and Y as it was unable to convert
End Try
```